# After turning the camera, the shapes are tilted OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

After the camera rotation on the Y axis and X and the subsequent move, is a strange camera rotation along the axis Z.
 For example, here is the normal state [image: All ok]
 but I was randomly moved around the stage, all twisted [image: Curvature]
 I do not know what to do and how to fix the problem, I hope for your help.
 I saw this question, it does not help me, because I do not even use glm, do not mark as a duplicate.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include "Camera.h"

using namespace std;

constexpr auto FPS_RATE = 120;
int windowHeight = 600, windowWidth = 600, windowDepth = 600;
float angle = 0, speedRatio = 0.25;
struct MyPoint3f
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};
MyPoint3f lastMousePos = { };
bool mouseButtonWasPressed = false;
float mouseSensitivity = 0.1;
float camMoveSpeed = 3;
float camPitchAngle = 0, camYawAngle = 0;
Camera cam;

void init();
void displayFunction();
void idleFunction();
void reshapeFunction(int, int);
void keyboardFunction(unsigned char, int, int);
void specialKeysFunction(int, int, int);
void mouseFunc(int, int, int, int);
void motionFunction(int, int);
double getTime();

double getTime()
{
    using Duration = std::chrono::duration<double>;
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<Duration>(
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
        ).count();
}

const double frame_delay = 1.0 / FPS_RATE;
double last_render = 0;

void init()
{
    glutDisplayFunc(displayFunction);
    glutIdleFunc(idleFunction);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshapeFunction);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboardFunction);
    glutMouseFunc(mouseFunc);
    glutMotionFunc(motionFunction);
    glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-windowWidth / 2, windowWidth / 2, -windowHeight / 2, windowHeight / 2, -windowDepth / 2, windowDepth / 2);
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    cam.setShape(45, (double)windowWidth / windowHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    cam.set(Point3(0, 0, 350), Point3(0, 0, 349), Vector3(0, 1, 0));
}

void displayFunction()
{
    angle += speedRatio;
    if (angle >= 360 || angle <= -360) angle = 0;
    if (camPitchAngle <= -360) camPitchAngle = 0;
    if (camPitchAngle >= 360) camPitchAngle = 0;
    if (camYawAngle <= -360) camYawAngle = 0;
    if (camYawAngle >= 360) camYawAngle = 0;
    cout << camPitchAngle << " " << camYawAngle << endl;
    cam.pitch(-(camPitchAngle *= mouseSensitivity));
    cam.yaw(-(camYawAngle *= mouseSensitivity));
    camPitchAngle = 0; camYawAngle = 0;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

    glPushMatrix();

    glRotatef(angle, 1, 0, 0);
    glRotatef(angle, 0, 1, 0);

    glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
    glutWireCube(150.0);

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 75; i += 5)
    {
        glVertex3i(i, 0, 0);
        glVertex3i(-i, 0, 0);
        glVertex3i(0, i, 0);
        glVertex3i(0, -i, 0);
        glVertex3i(0, 0, i);
        glVertex3i(0, 0, -i);
    }
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

    //RSHIFT and CTRL
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT))
    {
        cam.slide(0, 1.0 * camMoveSpeed, 0);
    }
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LCONTROL))
    {
        cam.slide(0, -1.0 * camMoveSpeed, 0);
    }

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void idleFunction()
{
    const double current_time = getTime();
    if ((current_time - last_render) > frame_delay)
    {
        last_render = current_time;
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}

void reshapeFunction(int w, int h)
{

}

void keyboardFunction(unsigned char key, int w, int h)
{
    switch (key)
    {
    case '+': case '=':
        speedRatio += 0.125;
        break;
    case '-': case '_':
        speedRatio -= 0.125;
        break;
    case 'A': case 'a':
        cam.slide(-1.0 * camMoveSpeed, 0, 0);
        break;
    case 'D': case 'd':
        cam.slide(1.0 * camMoveSpeed, 0, 0);
        break;
    case 'W': case 'w':
        cam.slide(0, 0, -1.0 * camMoveSpeed);
        break;
    case 'S': case 's':
        cam.slide(0, 0, 1.0 * camMoveSpeed);
        break;
    case 'Z': case 'z':
        cam.yaw(-1);
        break;
    case 'X': case 'x':
        cam.yaw(1);
        break;
    case 27:
        angle = 0;
        speedRatio = 0;
        cam.set(Point3(0, 0, 350), Point3(0, 0, 349), Vector3(0, 1, 0));
        break;
    default:
        cout << key << endl;
        break;
    }
}

void specialKeysFunction(int key, int x, int y)
{
    cout << key << endl;
}

void mouseFunc(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        mouseButtonWasPressed = true;
        lastMousePos.x = x;
        lastMousePos.y = y;
    }
}

void motionFunction(int mousePosX, int mousePosY)
{
    if (mousePosX >= 0 && mousePosX < windowWidth && mousePosY >= 0 && mousePosY < windowHeight)
    {
        if (mouseButtonWasPressed)
        {
            camPitchAngle += -mousePosY + lastMousePos.y;
            camYawAngle += mousePosX - lastMousePos.x;
            lastMousePos.x = mousePosX;
            lastMousePos.y = mousePosY;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    glutInitWindowPosition((GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - windowWidth) / 2, (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - windowHeight) / 2);
    glutCreateWindow("Window");
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

[Camera.h](https://github.com/EchoLiao/nalstudy/blob/869288a16e540520cadc28c82702e52f1c8396ac/books/c/cguo-e3/ch5/snowfall/Camera.h)
[Camera.cpp](https://github.com/EchoLiao/nalstudy/blob/869288a16e540520cadc28c82702e52f1c8396ac/books/c/cguo-e3/ch5/snowfall/Camera.cpp)

Comment: This sounds like gimbal lock, a common problem with ordering of rotations in 3D space. It is typically fixed by performing the rotations in parallel, or using quaternions which _do_ compose.

Comment: @gman, Okay, I've already posted all the code.

Comment: See https://www.flipcode.com/documents/matrfaq.html#Q36 and related entries

Comment: Try to change perspective. To something like `float fov_y_tan = static_cast<float>(windowHeight) / static_cast<float>(windowWidth); float aspect_ratio = static_cast<float>(windowWidth) / static_cast<float>(windowHeight);  const float h = fov_y_tan * (-windowDepth);const float w = h * aspect_ratio; glFrustum(h,w,-windowDepth,windowDepth);`

Comment: @VictorGubin, Your glFrustum() is missing two parameters. What to use?

Comment: Yep, should be `glFrustum(-w,w,-h,h, -windowDepth, windowDepth);`

Comment: Or simply use `gluPerspective(fov_y, aspect_ratio, zNear, zFar);` where fov_y is atan of foy_y_tan

Comment: @VictorGubin, Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem.

Comment: You haven't posted all the code though. I have no what you camera class does as it's not **in the question itself** as required by Stack Overflow. Also, FYI: You might want to consider learning [modern OpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/) instead of old deprecated desktop only OpenGL

Comment: *"After the camera rotation on the Y axis and X and the subsequent move, is a strange camera rotation along the axis Z."* - Yes  and No. It appears to be a rotation around the z-axis, but in fact first the camera is rotated around the y-axis, then the rotated model is rotated around the x-axis. The result is correct, there is no error or bug. Skip one of the rotations and you'll see that it works.

Comment: @Rabbid76, Well, can you advise me what to do in my code to eliminate this effect?

Comment: @German  `glRotatef(angle, 0, 1, 0);`  then `glRotatef(angle, 1, 0, 0);` - see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

> ```cpp
> glRotatef(angle, 1, 0, 0);
> glRotatef(angle, 0, 1, 0);
> ```

Then the model is rotated around the y-axis and then the rotated model is rotated around the x-axis, because [`glRotatef`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRotate.xml) sets a rotation matrix and multiplies it to the current matrix.
Because the model is rotated around the y-axis before it is rotated around the x-axis, the (view space) y-axis is kept it the yz-plane of the view space.

[image]

If you want to keep the x-axis in the xz-plane of the view space, you've to do the rotation around the x-axis first:

```cpp
glRotatef(angle, 0, 1, 0);
glRotatef(angle, 1, 0, 0);
```

[image]

---

The same issue occurs when you apply `pich()` and `yaw()` to the camera object. If you switch it (first `yaw()` then `pitch()`), then that won't solve the issue, because pitch and yaw are applied incrementally by each mouse move (`pich()`, `yaw()`, `pich()`, `yaw()`, `pich()`, `yaw()` ...). So there is always a `yaw()` after a `pitch()` and the model gets tilted.

To solve the issue you've to sum up `camPitchAngle` and `camYawAngle`. Take into account the mouse intensity:

```cpp
void motionFunction(int mousePosX, int mousePosY)
{
    if (mousePosX >= 0 && mousePosX < windowWidth && mousePosY >= 0 && mousePosY < windowHeight)
    {
        if (mouseButtonWasPressed)
        {
            camPitchAngle += (-mousePosY + lastMousePos.y) * mouseSensitivity;
            camYawAngle   += (mousePosX - lastMousePos.x) * mouseSensitivity;
            lastMousePos.x = mousePosX;
            lastMousePos.y = mousePosY;
        }
    }
}
```

Copy the camera object (`cam` / `curr_cam`) in `displayFunction` and apply `camPitchAngle` and `camYawAngle` to the copy. Use the copy to set the view and projection matrix:

```cpp
void displayFunction()
{
    // [...]

    // cam.pitch(-(camPitchAngle *= mouseSensitivity)); <--- delete
    // cam.yaw(-(camYawAngle *= mouseSensitivity));     <--- delete

    // [...]

    Camera curr_cam = cam;
    curr_cam.yaw( -camYawAngle );
    curr_cam.pitch( -camPitchAngle );

    // [...]

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LSHIFT))
    {
        curr_cam.slide(0, 1.0 * camMoveSpeed, 0);
    }
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LCONTROL))
    {
        curr_cam.slide(0, -1.0 * camMoveSpeed, 0);
    }

    // [...]   
}
```

Of course you've to set `camYawAngle = 0` respectively `camPitchAngle = 0;` when <kbd>z</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd> or <kbd>ESC</kbd> is pressed.

Comment: But even without turning the cube itself, this effect remains. After moving to some point, for example to another face, everything is bent.

Comment: I completely removed `glRotatef(angle, 1, 0, 0);
glRotatef(angle, 0, 1, 0);` from my code, now when I move the camera around the cube by controlling the mouse, then when I look at the cube again, it is tilted.

Comment: What do I do, so that would not be a model does not bend?

Comment: I don't understand how the copy camera will be able to solve everything. Please look at this modified version of the code.  The copy of the camera didn't change anything. [Look this code](https://pastebin.com/0nMBhka6)

Comment: @German Of course you've to delete `cam.pitch(...)` and `cam.yaw(...)`. See the answer.

Comment: Perfectly. But alas, now I can not move in the direction of viewing, I move along the axes of the world, but not the camera. For example, I can not look somewhere and fly forward. That's not what I was trying to do.

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot.